# /actuator/health is calling RedisReactiveHealthIndicator instead of RedisHealthIndicator in a non-reactive spring boot app

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

My spring boot application is non-reactive in nature. However, when I am invoking /actuator/health URL, the health indicator its calling is RedisReactiveHealthIndicator instead of RedisHealthIndicator. This is causing intermittent timeout issues in the PCF health check. Is there any way we can override RedisReactiveHealthIndicator with RedisHealthIndicator.